# value of set::find() if not found in container

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, c++17

I am trying to understand `std::find()`. Below is my code.

> `std::set::find` searches the container for an element equivalent to
> `val` and returns an iterator to it if found, **otherwise it returns an
> iterator to `set::end`**.

But when I gave `find(100)` I am getting 7 rather than 20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set <int> s1{20, 7, 2};
    s1.insert(10);
    s1.insert(5);
    s1.insert(15);
    s1.insert(1);
    
    cout << "size()     : " << s1.size() << endl;
    cout << "max_size() : " << s1.max_size() << endl;
    cout << "empty()    : " << s1.empty() << endl;
    
    for(auto itr = s1.begin(); itr != s1.end(); itr++)
        cout << *itr << " ";
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << endl << "---- find(value) ----" << endl;
    auto a1 = s1.find(10);
    //cout << "find(10)  : " << a1 << " " << *a1 << endl;
    cout << "find(10)  : " << *a1 << endl;
    auto a2 = s1.find(100);
    cout << "find(100) : " << *a2 << endl;
    
    cout << endl << "---- count(value) ----" << endl;
    cout << "s1.count(10) : " << s1.count(10) << endl;
    cout << "s1.count(100) : " << s1.count(100) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
size()     : 7

max_size() : 107374182

empty()    : 0

1 2 5 7 10 15 20

---- find(value) ----

find(10)  : 10

find(100) : 7


---- count(value) ----

s1.count(10) : 1

s1.count(100) : 0
```

Comment: `.end()` doesn't point to the last element, it points to a non-existent element after the last one. Derefencing it causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> auto a2 = s1.find(100);
> cout << "find(100) : " << *a2 << endl;
> ```

Here you dereference (`*a2`) the end iterator.  That is undefined behaviour - remember that `s1.end()` points to *one past the last element* and must not be dereferenced.

You're unlucky that you got a value from that dereference - it would be more convenient if your program crashed or otherwise reported the problem.  But UB doesn't have to be diagnosed in any way.

You might have spotted the problem if you had run your program using Valgrind's memory checker (or your preferred equivalent).  But there's a good chance that's unable to detect it (if the set has over-allocated, which is likely).

Comment: Thank you. I missed the point of end() points to one past the last element.

Answer (score 3):

The **problem** is that you're dereferencing an iterator `a2` that points to `s1.end()` leading to **undefined behavior**. This problem arose because you're not checking before dereferencing the iterators, if the element was found or not.

To **solve** this you should add an explicit check before dereferencing the iterators.

```
//dereference only if the element was found
if(a2!=s1.end())
{
   std::cout << "find(100) : " << *a2 << std::endl; 
}
//otherwise print a message saying element not found 
else 
{
    std::cout<<"element not found"<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value 100 is not present in the set. So this call

```
auto a2 = s1.find(100);
```

returns the iterator `s1.end()`. You may not dereference the iterator. This statement

```
cout << "find(100) : " << *a2 << endl;
```

invokes undefined behavior.